# Can't build app installer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, installation

I'm building **msi** installer **for webapp** to setup on client servers. I have webapp working great, and I have **.vdproj installer** that I can't build because of following errors:

```
Unable to build project output group 'Content Files from X.Hosts.IIS (Active)'
```

I've investigated dependencies and found I have duplicated **System.Net.Http** libs

[image]

Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to install two or more copies of the same file in the same folder. Only one copy can be installed; however, multiple copies can be placed in the same folder in the **File System Editor** provided that each has a unique condition.
**To correct this error**
1. Double-click the error in the **Task List** to go to the file in the **File System Editor**.
2. Delete the duplicate file, or select the **Condition** property in the **Properties** window for each copy of the file and enter a unique condition for each.
**Read more:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhx4ah11(v=vs.80).aspx